# Loop through items into Django 1.8 template

Tags: python, django, github-api

I have this method:

```
def profile(request):
    parsedData = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('user')
        req = requests.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + username + '/repos') 
        jsonList = []
        jsonList=req.json()
        userData = {}
        for data in jsonList:
            userData['html_url'] = data['html_url']
            userData['created_at'] = data['created_at']
            userData['updated_at'] = data['updated_at']
            userData['forks_count'] = data['forks_count']
        parsedData.append(userData)
    return render(request, 'app/profile.html', {'data': parsedData})
```

This code looks into an url like this [githubtraining](https://api.github.com/users/githubtraining/repos)

As You can see, the response contains lots of repositories, however, not every github user has more than 1 repo.

Anyways, on my html view I have this:

```
  <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped tablesorter">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="header"> Url <i class="icon-sort"></i></th>
            <th class="header"> Created at <i class="icon-sort"></i></th>
            <th class="header"> Updated at <i class="icon-sort"></i></th>
            <th class="header"> Forks count <i class="icon-sort"></i></th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      {% for key in data %}
          <tr>
              <td>{{ key.html_url }}</td>
              <td>{{ key.created_at }}</td>
              <td>{{ key.updated_at }}</td>
              <td>{{ key.forks_count }}</td>
          </tr>
      {% endfor %}

      </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
```

What happens then? Well, right now, if, for instance, I query the `githubtraining` user to see it's repos, it shows only the last one, on that and every other user, so, what am I doing wrong here? The loop is there, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You append data only after forloop is finished inside your view. You need to append it after each iteration instead:

```
for data in jsonList:
    userData = {}
    userData['html_url'] = data['html_url']
    userData['created_at'] = data['created_at']
    userData['updated_at'] = data['updated_at']
    userData['forks_count'] = data['forks_count']
    parsedData.append(userData)
```

With your current code:

```
userData = {} 
for data in jsonList:
    userData['html_url'] = data['html_url']
    userData['created_at'] = data['created_at']
    userData['updated_at'] = data['updated_at']
    userData['forks_count'] = data['forks_count']
parsedData.append(userData)
```

new userData overrides previous one inside for cycle. And when cycle finishing you have only one record in the list.

Comment: Oops, but one thing, it shows me only the last one (repo) plenty of times, lol, is that normal?

Comment: @NeoVe also you need to move `userData = {}` inside the loop. See update.